# Seeing which part of code MatLab is currently running

Tags: matlab

I am trying to debug a very large MatLab program.

But when it is running, if there is something that shows me which line of the code it is currently running, it will be easier to detect mistake and debug it later.

What I have tried is just looking at the variable list. But variables which are getting updated in sub-function don't appear in the list. And they are not shown until the code hits some error or it ends.

Does MatLab have that?

Comment: Add break points in your subfunction; then you'll be able to inspect the variables in its scope/workspace.

Comment: or if you get 2016a you will have the pause option.